# How to separate heading digits from a string with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string in the form of

```
$str = '0.5An55.5Tik';
```

and want to separate the heading number as

```
$number = '0.5';
$str = 'An55.5Tik'
```

I came up with the idea of

```
$array = preg_split('/(^[0-9.]+)(.*?)/i',$str);
```

but the regex doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
$results = preg_split('~^\d*\.?\d+\K~', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMdkJH/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all the text matched so far.

You may also get the values into groups by matching:

```
preg_match('~^(\d*\.?\d+)(.*)~', $s, $m)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lq1Nnl/1) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/AwhfZl):

```
$s = '0.5An55.5Tik';
if (preg_match('/^(\d*\.?\d+)(.*)/', $s, $m)) {
 echo $m[1] . "\n" . $m[2];
}
```

Here, `(\d*\.?\d+)` will place the number into Group 1 and `(.*)` will put the rest of the string into Group 2.

Output:

```
0.5
An55.5Tik
```

Comment: Very subtle approach and works like a charm. But, how to modify the regex to work for `An55.5Tik` too. When there is no heading digit (sorry, I had to explain it in the original question). Of course, your edit for `if(preg_match) `does the job, but isn't it better to do with the regex?

Comment: @Googlebot What is the requirement for `An55.5Tik`? What is the expected output? `if(preg_match)` is only to check if there was a match, it *is* done with regex, it is a `preg_match` function.

Comment: Also, see https://ideone.com/qT1Gr3 - is that what you need? Add `.*?` after `^`.

Comment: It was just a follow-up question for learning. Your solution works perfectly.